# How to access datagridview in C# using White framework?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, ui-automation, white-framework

I am new to UI automation testing. Currently I am using TestStack. `White framework` to access UI elements with `UI Spy`.

In my testing script, I am trying  to access datagridview to select a row and do    some operation.

```
table = _newWindow.Get<TestStack.White.UIItems.TableItems.Table>
  (SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("dataGridView1"));
```

But I always get below error, even though my automation id is correct.

> "TestStack.White.AutomationException: Failed to get ControlType=table,AutomationId=dataGridView1"

Is this the correct way to search `datagridview` in a form using White framework?

Using .NET framework 4.5

Comment: Is it native grid of MS or 3rd party's framework control? Can you attach a screenshot from UI spy or other similar tool for this control?